# Is it possible to connect a Windows 10 IoT UWP C# application on a Raspberry Pi 3 to a bluetooth headset?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I'm working on an universal application running in a Rpi3 with Windows 10 IoT 14393.67 using speech synthesis and recognition. I've been using an USB microphone for the input and the audio jack connected to speakers for the synthetized voice, but I wanted to change it to use a bluetooth headset instead.

I've paired a headset to the device using the integrated bluetooth connection in the Rpi3, but I couldn't figure out how to access the microphone and the speakers on the headset from my c# code. Is this possible to archieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP apps can do quite advanced stuff even on the Raspberry Pi. What you described is quite common and Microsoft even provides a set of Bluetooth related samples to get started with:

[Device enumeration and pairing sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing)

You might also want to take a look at the [Bluetooth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/bluetooth) section of UWP documentation on MSDN.

Comment: Thank you hankide! I've found these links very usefull!